# Liability for US taxes on foreign company held by non-US citizen spouse?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, non-resident, self-employment, foreign-income

I am a U.S. citizen, but my wife is not. If I own a foreign company, I am subject to [Section 965 Transition Tax](https://www.irs.gov/businesses/section-965-transition-tax), [Form 5471](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/certain-taxpayers-related-to-foreign-corporations-must-file-form-5471) and [Self Employment Tax](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/self-employment-tax-for-businesses-abroad) regardless of where I live.

If we are living outside of the U.S., will my non-U.S. wife's business income be subject to [Section 965 Transition Tax](https://www.irs.gov/businesses/section-965-transition-tax), [Form 5471](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/certain-taxpayers-related-to-foreign-corporations-must-file-form-5471) and [Self Employment Tax](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/self-employment-tax-for-businesses-abroad) simply because I am married to her? What if I am employed by her company?

Comment: Some info is missing - does your wife have a green card? do you file joint returns? why are you subject to self-employment tax just because you own  a foreign company? why kind of "company" is the foreign company? etc.

Comment: @JackFleeting She does not have a green card. We file joint tax returns while we live here in the US. If I owned the company and worked for it, I would be self-employed. Similar to https://e-resident.gov.ee/start-a-company/, but in Latvia

Answer (score 1):

Let's start at the end: you should really talk to a tax professional before you make any decisions.

Your wife is a non-greed-card holding resident alien; she can become a nonresident alien once you move abroad, but even that isn't as intutitive as it seems. Once she is a nonresident alien, she may want to stop filing jointly with you, or maybe elect to contintue to do so - there are some benefits to that.  [Check out this, for starters.](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/nonresident-alien-spouse)

The fact that you own a company and work for it doesn't mean you are self-employed. On the contrary - you are probably an employee; it's possible to be self employed under those circumstances if the company is treated as a partnership/LLC for US tax purposes, but that, too, isn't simple to determine.

Really, talk to a professional....

Answer (score -1):

If she is no longer a US resident, then she should not be liable for US taxes.

My wife is a US citizen and I am not. She works for a company I own (more importantly, she owns less than 10% of it). She does not pay self-employment tax to the USA.

Comment: How did you get to the 10% number?

Comment: I think that was the threshold for significant control.